# Добавление нескольких доменов в Cloudflare через консоль

Tags: cloudflare, cdn

Столкнулся с такой проблемой, никак не могу разобраться как с помощью консоли добавить домены в  cloudflare. Кто сталкивался, подскажите пожалуйста.
Пытаюсь так: (логинюсь)

```
export CF_API_EMAIL=you@example.com
export CF_API_KEY=abc123def456ghi789
```

Дальше через `for` хочу добавить домены из файла

```
for domain in $(cat domains.txt); do \
curl -X POST -H "X-Auth-Key: $CF_API_KEY" -H "X-Auth-Email: $CF_API_EMAIL" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
"https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones" \
--data '{"name":"'$domain'","jump_start":true}'; done
```

Но я даже не могу залогинится. Подскажите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

У вас зона задана неправильно. Посмотрите, выглядит мой рабочий код по добавлению CNAME через API CloudFlare

```
curl -s -X POST "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/zones/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/dns_records" \
-H "X-Auth-Email: mail@example.com" \
-H "X-Auth-Key: yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
--data '{"type":"CNAME","name":"'$1'","content":"domain.com"}' > /dev/null
```